# nuxt's npm run build stuck because of nuxt-mongoose

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

I have a problem regarding on nuxt-mongoose during nuxt build. Everything is running fine on nuxt dev. it's just at during nuxt build, the command never finishes and just stuck here. I deployed my app on netlify so, because of this thing, it fails to deploy because of expired runtime.

```
Total size: 52.8 MB (19.8 MB gzip)
✔ You can preview this build using node .output/server/index.mjs 
├─ /__sitemap__/routes.json (0ms)
```

I am positive it's the nuxt-mongoose because I tried removing it from my app, and the build command finishes.

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.1",
    "nuxt-simple-robots": "^3.1.2",
    "nuxt-simple-sitemap": "^3.2.6",
    "sass": "^1.63.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@nuxt/image-edge": "^1.0.0-rc.1-28143901.afe4120",
    "@nuxtjs/cloudinary": "^2.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "nuxt-mongoose": "^0.0.9"
  }
}
```

~/server/model/profile.js

```js
import { defineMongooseModel } from '#nuxt/mongoose'

export const ProfileSchema = defineMongooseModel({
    name: 'profiles',
    schema: {
        name: String,
        desc: String,
        country: String,
        city: String,
        skills  : [{
            skill: String,
            level: String
        }],
        languages: [{
            skill: String,
            level: String
        }]
    },
})
```

~/server/api/profile.js

```js
export default eventHandler( async () => {

    try {
        return await ProfileSchema.findOne()
    } catch (e) {
        throw createError({ statusCode: 404, statusMessage: 'Page Not Found' })
    }
    
})
```

nuxt.config.ts

```js
import 'dotenv/config'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  app: {
    head: {
      charset: 'utf-8',
      viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
      htmlAttrs: { lang: 'en', },
    }
  },
  css: [ '~/assets/scss/main.scss', ],
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: { additionalData: '@import "@/assets/scss/_variables";' }
      }
    }
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/cloudinary',
    '@nuxt/image-edge',
    'nuxt-simple-sitemap',
    'nuxt-simple-robots',
    'nuxt-mongoose',
  ],
  image: {
    cloudinary: {
      baseURL: `https://res.cloudinary.com/${process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload/v1693287581`
    }
  },
  nitro: {
    prerender: {
      routes: ['/portfolio', '/contact','/history'],
    },
  },
  site: {
    url: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },
  mongoose: {
    uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    options: {},
    modelsDir: 'models',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed, check this issue and the latest 1.0.2 version of nuxt-mongoose

https://github.com/arashsheyda/nuxt-mongoose/issues/25